# failed to install modules

Tags: python, installation, module

I am writing a code with spyder and trying to install a module, joypy.
In a console, I typed `conda install -c conda-forge joypy` and I got this error below

```
CondaSSLError: Encountered an SSL error. Most likely a certificate verification issue.

Exception: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='conda.anaconda.org', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /conda-forge/win-64/current_repodata.json (Caused by SSLError(SSLCertVerificationError(1, '[SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed: unable to get local issuer certificate (_ssl.c:997)')))"
```

Could you let me know how to install the modules?

I updated the spyder and python, but it did not resolve the issue

Comment: Are you on Windows?

Comment: Yes, I am on windoes